# Seeking Smart Contract for Certifying Physical Artworks Similar to Kronos360

Tags: solidity, tokens, nft, erc-721, certification

I'm looking for a smart contract that can certify physical artworks, similar to Kronos360's approach for watches. The contract should mint a unique token for each artwork, linked to its image and metadata stored on IPFS, ensuring authenticity and traceability.

I've had difficulty understanding the Kronos360 contract due to decompiling issues. Can anyone recommend a similar contract, or provide guidance on how to build or adapt one for this purpose? Insights into best practices for blockchain-based art certification are also welcome.

Thanks!